# Problem with find all element child in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, assertion

I am new in TestCafe. I have a problem with the function child().
I want to define a variable (Collection) using Selector, but I am doing something wrong.

My code:

```
`import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

test('foo', async t => {

 await t

const childCount = Selector('.someClassSelector').child().count;

await t
.expect(Selector('.someClassSelector').child().count).eql(childCount);

});
`
```

Test crashed with AssertionError: expected 10 to deeply equal { Object (_then, _fn, ...) }

I expected that the test will be passed.

Can somebody please explain to me, why the test crashed?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You seem to forgot to add the await keyword:

`const childCount = await Selector('.someClassSelector').child().count;`

I recommend that you refer to the [Obtain Element State](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#obtain-element-state) topic where this inquiry is described.